# Can I mix and match cogs from 2 different SRAM cassettes and still expect it to work?

Tags: gears, cassette

My road bike currently has a 12-25 cassette on it.  I really want the cog with 11 teeth instead of the cog with 12 teeth, but I don't want to upgrade to a full 11-32.  If I were to install a new 12-25 cassette on by bike, but replaced the 12 tooth cog with a 11 tooth cog (effectively creating a franken-cassette) would it still work?  Or are the cogs in a cassette not made to be mixed and matched like this?

It's assumed that both of these cassettes would be general SRAM cassettes, but I'm not talking about cassettes like the XG-1190 that have "compatibility notices".

And as a follow up question, would I need to re-calibrate the shifting mechanism after having created this "franken-cassette"?   The number of cogs would effectively remain the same, so I'm hoping not.

Comment: They sell 11-25 cassette.  Are you not finding what you want?   Correct you should not need to re-calibrate.

Comment: Yeah, its possible, but the question is why, versus buying the Shimano/SRAM cassette which is 11-25 already? And on top of that, are you really spinning out on your 12 ?

Comment: there isn't much difference between an 11 and 12 tooth cog.  Assuming you are running a road bike with a 50 tooth chainring, an 11 tooth cog will make you go 51.7 KM/h at 90 rpm while the 12 tooth chainring will make you go 47.4 KM/h. Most people would struggle to make the bike go that fast.

Comment: 1 tooth difference between adjacent cogs is MOST noticeable in the smaller cogs.  About 9% in this case.  That would be like changing 3 teeth on the largest cog (such as 36 to 33).

Comment: Are you riding 10 or 11 speed? I'm pretty sure sram doesn't do a 12-25 in 11 speed, but as frisbee said they do an 11-25, but it's 11 speed, at least mine is.  I'd prefer to have the 12-25 because you get a better ratio up top where you're using it more, usually the 18 tooth cog. Rarely is an average rider spinning out an 11-53 or even a compact on an 11.

Comment: I was more concerned about the feasibility of mixing and matching cogs than the wisdom behind jumping from 12 to 11 or 11 to 10 on the smallest cog.  Practically  I don't spin out on the smallest cog yet, but I am heading to NC in april and I want to see how fast I can get going on some of the descents with a smaller cog.   I also have noted that my derailleur has difficulty with 10 cog cassettes so I'm not of the mindset to jump up to an 10 cog cassette with this bike.

Comment: @Jason If that is the question then you have an answer.   You confused the question with that other stuff.   With descend comes ascend - this 11(skip) 25 is making less and less sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

absolutely, I do it all the time. just make sure they are sequential. (ie. 11t 13t, 14t etc)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35730/discussion-on-answer-by-will-evers-can-i-mix-and-match-cogs-from-2-different-sra).